# Drops of urine after ablution

Tags: fiqh, practical-islam, taharah

As Salam alaikum. I have already asked questions on this topic, but I want to clarify something else. I have prostatitis. And after urinating, you need to wait a few minutes, for example, 5-10 minutes, so that the drops come out. After that time, they don't seem to come out. Everything dries up. And with this one ablution, I do all the prayers, and Imam Shafi'i said that it is necessary to take an ablution for incontinence before each prayer.

It turns out that my prayers are invalid?

And one more thing. It so happens that on my tip of the genital organ after exactly ablution, either water or urine is on the surface.

What to do in such a situation?

It's one thing if a drop comes out by pressing on the head, then it's urine, and it happens that I look after ablution, and there is already water or urine on the surface.

And is it right that after washing I often look and check whether there is urine or not?

Answer (score 1):

Wa alaikkum wa salaam,

I understand your concern. This condition of prostatitis is given by Allah, Allah knows the problems associated with it. Don't get too concerned about few drops of urine. There are disease where urine flow non stop and for those patients the advice given is just take ablution just before prayer and even if urine pass during prayer, it is not an issue as they have no control. So understand that Allah is pardoning (Afwun عَفُوٌّ ) , just take ablution before each time you pray and forget about urine drops and concentrate on prayer.